# Delphi: Generic classes don't work for Android

Tags: android, delphi, generics

I am trying to write a generic class for loading and storing objects in JSON format. This is my code:

```
type
  TFileHandler<T:class, constructor> = class
  published
    class function LoadFromFile(aFileName: string):T;
    class procedure SaveToFile(value: T; aFileName: string);
  end;

implementation

{ TFileHandler<T> }

class function TFileHandler<T>.LoadFromFile(aFileName: string): T;

var
  strings: TStringList;

begin
  if aFileName = '' then begin
    aFileName := TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath,'sample.txt');
  end; {if}
  if FileExists(aFileName) then begin
    strings := TStringList.Create;
    strings.LoadFromFile(aFileName);
    result := TJSON.JsonToObject<T>(strings.Text);
    strings.free();
  end
  else begin
    result := T.Create();
  end; {if}
end;

class procedure TFileHandler<T>.SaveToFile(value: T; aFileName: string);

var
  strings: TStringList;

begin
  if aFileName = '' then begin
    aFileName := TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath,'sample.txt');
  end; {if}
  strings := TStringList.Create;
  strings.Add(TJson.ObjectToJsonString(value));
  strings.SaveToFile(aFileName);
  strings.Free;
end;
```

I am using my class in another unit:

```
FFileHandler := TFileHandler<TUser>.Create;

procedure TMainForm.btnStoreClick(Sender: TObject);

var
  aFileName: string;
  strings: TStringList;
begin
  FUser.Name := PersonalData.edtName.Text;
  FUser.FirstName := PersonalData.edtFirstName.Text;
  FUser.MobileNumber := PersonalData.edtTelephone.Text;
  FUser.EMailAddress := PersonalData.edtEMail.Text;

  aFileName := TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath,'sample.txt');
  FFileHandler.SaveToFile(FUser,TPath.Combine(TPath.GetHomePath,'testuser.json'));
end;
```

This all works great under 32-bit Windows, but when I try to use this code on an android device, I cannot even set breakpoints inside the class functions (the breakpoints are marked as invalid).

Is there a problem with generic classes and Android? Or am I missing something?

Thanks

Kaspar

Comment: This should be a QC report I guess.

Comment: Is the problem that your breakpoints don't work, that the code doesn't work, or both?  If the code doesn't work, does it compile?  Does it crash?  Are there error messages?  What is the behaviour and how is this different from the behaviour under Win32?

Comment: Hi DaveThe code compiles, there are no error messages, the code just does not execute. Under Windows the file exists after SaveToFile, in Android there is no file around.

Comment: If you cannot set a breakpoint, make sure that you are compiling in debug mode and not release mode.  If you cannot find the file, are you sure that you are saving it where you think you are saving it? Check the documentation for `GetDocumentsPath` - if you haven't created a documents directory for your application yet it may not exist and this function may return an empty string :  http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.IOUtils.TPath.GetDocumentsPath

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The project is definitely compiled in debug mode. I replaced my generic class with direct calls to ObjectToJsonString and then it works. The file path evaluates to "/data/data/com.embarcadero.userapp/files/samples.txt".

Comment: Uses Permission to write data is set.